# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, using dictionaries

Tags: python

Im having trouble understanding the error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, I've been finding solution regarding this but to no avail as I also have a little knowledge with this one, please help me.

```
# Printing all the medicine items in store
print("------------------------------------------------- Store Items --------------------------------------------------")
print("Code - Item name                                         |   Code - Item Name")
print("(B1) Advil Softget 200mg cap (Piece)            - 10.00  |  (10050) Allerta 10mg 2+1 tab (pack)        - 47.00  | ")
print("(B2) Alaxan FR cap (piece)                      - 9.00   |  (10051) Alnix drops 10ml syrup (bottle)    - 209.00 | ")
print("(B3) Allerkid 2.5mg drops 10 (bottle)           - 184.00 |  (10052) Alnix 5mg/60ml syrup (bottle)      - 300.00 | ")
print("(B4) Allerkid 5mg/30ml syrup (bottle)           - 168.00 |  (10053) Amlife 50mg/5mg tablet (piece)     - 26.00  | ")
print("(B5) 5mg/60ml syrup (bottle)                    - 294.00 |  (10054) Amlife 100mg/5mg tablet (piece)    - 31.00  |")
print("(B6) Alvedon 500mg tab (piece)                  - 5.00   |  (10055) Arcoxia 90mg tablet (piece)        - 70.00  |")
print("(B7) Appebon kid 120mlsyrup (bottle)            - 188.00 |  (10056) Arcoxia 120mg tablet (piece)       - 87.00  | ")
print("(B8) Asccof Ponakn 60ml syrup (bottle)          - 108.00 |  (10106) Alnix 10mg tab                     - 33.00  |")
print("(B9) Asferon 60ml syrup (bottle)                - 117.00 |  (10107) Ascof ponkan 60ml syrup (bottle)   - 108.00 |")
print("(B10) Aspilet 80mg tablet (piece)               - 4.00   |  (10108) Asferon gf 60ml syrup              - 117.00 | ")
print("(B11) Bioflu tab (piece)                        - 8.00   |  (10109) Azuthromycin-AZITERA 500mg tab     - 110.00 |")
print("(B12) Biogesic 15ml drops (bottle)              - 73.00  |  (10114) Ambroxol EXPEL 15ml drops (bottle) - 118.00 | ")
print("(B13) Biogesic 500mg tab (piece)                - 5.00   |  (10135) Betadine 10% 25ml soln (bottle)    - 98.00  | ")
print("(B14) Biogesic 500mg tab (piece)                - 5.00   |  (10262) Alaxan Tablet                      - 9.00   |")
print("(B15) Biogesic Orange 120mg 60ml syrup (bottle) - 86.00  |      ")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
# Using dictionaries to store code items purchase value
store_items = {"b1": 10.0, "b2": 9.0, "b3": 184.0, "b4": 168.0, "b5": 294.0, "b6": 5.0, "b7": 188.0, "b8": 108.0, "b9": 117.0, "b10": 4.0, "b11": 8.0,
     "b12": 73.0, "b13": 5.0, "b14": 5.0, "b15": 86.0, "10050": 47.0, "10051": 209.0, "10052": 300.0, "10053": 26.0, "10054": 31.0, "10055": 70.0,
     "10056": 87.0, "10106": 33.0, "10107": 108.0, "10108": 117.0, "10109": 110.0, "10114": 118.0, "10135": 98.0, "102622": 9.0}
# Calling for initial value
container = []
total = []
# Defining function for purchase processes
def cashier():
   user_select = input("Please enter the product code of the item that you wish to purchase: ").lower()
   while user_select != "quit":
       if user_select in store_items:
           container.append(user_select)
           user_select = input("item added in container, do you wish to add more? (type quit to end transaction): ").lower()
       else:
           user_select = input("Invalid, item selected is not on store item, still want to add more? (type quit to end transaction): ").lower()

cashier()
print("Here are all the items that you wish to purchased: {0}".format(container))
# Prompts the user to try again
retry = input("Do you still wish to add more items? (type: yes/no): ")
if retry == "yes" or retry == "Yes":
   cashier()
   print("Here are all the items that you wish to purchase {0}".format(container))
   for store_items in container:
       total.append(container[store_items])
   total_amount_pay = sum(total)
else:
   for store_items in container:
       total.append(container[store_items])
   total_amount_pay = sum(total)

print("Your total amount to pay is ", total_amount_pay)
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then create a [mre], [edit] your question and do not forgot to include the full stack trace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment on your question notes, there is an issue with the following block

```
for store_items in container:
    total.append(container[store_items])
total_amount_pay = sum(total)
```

Note that each element `store_items` is actually a product code from the container, not an index. What I suspect you're trying to do is something like the following.

```
for code in container:
    total.append(store_items[code])
total_amount_pay = sum(total)
```

Comment: Thank you!, got confused on this part of the code.